# MySQL result select SUM from the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following tables and I try to select from table1, table2 and table3 and sum them in total:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_cars` (
  `carID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `car` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product1_amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product2_amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product3_amount` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tbl_cars` (`carID`, `car`, `product1`, `product1_amount`, `product2`, `product2_amount`, `product3`, `product3_amount`) VALUES
(1, 'Kamacho 180 PS', 1, 10, 0, 0, 3, 10),
(2, 'Komoda 123 PS', 1, 20, 2, 20, 0, 0);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_orders` (
  `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ordered` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pending` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `money` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idcard` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `account` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tbl_orders` (`orderID`, `name`, `ordered`, `pending`, `status`, `money`, `number`, `idcard`, `date`, `account`) VALUES
(1, 'Some_Name', '1', 1, 0, '1000', '1822-25136145', 21474836471, '2020-11-26 05:44:00', '');

CREATE TABLE `tbl_prices` (
  `priceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `tbl_prices`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_prices` (`priceID`, `product`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'Rolle Stoff', 5.00),
(2, 'Rolle Pappe', 10.00),
(3, 'Eiesenbarren', 15.00),
(4, 'Rolle Stoff123', 20.00),
(5, 'Rolle Pappe123', 25.00),
(6, 'Eiesenbarren123', 30.00);
```

What i've done is currently this

```
SELECT product1_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars WHERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product1
UNION
SELECT product2_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars WHERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product2
UNION
SELECT product3_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars WHERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product3
```

result

```
total
50
150
```

So far so good, but i'm looking for this result

```
total
200
```

I tried with

```
SELECT SUM(total) total FROM (
SELECT product1_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars WHERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product1
UNION
SELECT product2_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars WHERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product2
UNION
SELECT product3_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars WHERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product3
)t
GROUP BY total
```

but this result is still the same result as the first one

```
total
50
150
```

Searched now about a hour on google to find a solution and this was my best try to get any result at all what i'm looking for. If there is also a better solution i'd really like to learn more about it.
Anyway for any fix for my question would be amazing.

EDIT:

sample data
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c063a7/4

Comment: Are you aware that you are currently doing a cross join between the three tables?  This probably isn't what you want.

Comment: I don't im kinda new to SQL and trying to figure out how this done. If you have a better solution i'd love to see it that I can learn from this.

Comment: Add sample data to your question.

Comment: I added sample data to my question

Comment: Should, in your first query, you not use `UNION ALL` in stead of `UNION` ???  That would change the result to have 3 results....

Comment: Why should I need 3 results instead of 1? As I said i'm looking for a result who sum the result as total not as 3.

Comment: @HannaTeobald What is the purpose of the union if you get the same data from each of its part (e.g. two products are the same)? Or if it is not the case so there's no difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, but the latter is faster. The purpose of `GROUP BY` is to calculate aggregated value grouped by some columns, so for single order you do not need to group by something or can group by `orderid`. Also prefer join via `JOIN` clause instead of `WHERE` clause and use each column with its source name like `table_name.column_name` because it is easier to read and debug.

Comment: The SQL what i've checks first of all the orderID. Than it will check the ordered with the carID and select the products and find the price in the prices table, so I can sum them in total that I can count the full price. I mean i'm trying to do this. I already said, if there is any better solution as i already have done i'm ready to learn from any example I can get or any better solution. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Start by fixing your schema. Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can be sure that your design is sub-optimal. (Also, I find the business of prefixing tables with 'tbl_' utterly bizarre - but each to their own I guess)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to find the total the u have to sum all the individual totals not union them

```
 SELECT
  ISNULL(( SELECT product1_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars WHERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product1 ),0)
  +
  ISNULL(( SELECT product2_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars WHERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product2 ),0)
  +
  ISNULL(( SELECT product3_amount*price as total FROM tbl_prices, tbl_orders, tbl_cars HERE orderID = '1' AND ordered = carID AND priceID = product3),0)
 as total;
```

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is, if product1 = 10, product2 = NULL and product3 = 20 the result will be NULL because of the product2 = NULL. Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: Yes you are right. I will update my answer to consider that. Thanks for finding it out

Comment: The problem with "ISNULL" is not working for me. So I changed it to "IFNULL" and that is working as I want it. Thanks for your reply.